# Measure frequencies fast and precise

Tags: frequency-measurement

I need to measure frequencies between 25kHz and 150kHz with a precision of minimum 50Hz. I'm using a MCU 8051(C8051F382 Silicon) with 48MHz clock, and need the measure to be done under 100us, so I can't use CD4040/prescaler to get many counts.
I need a high precision because my reference isn't stable, it drifts during day.
Is PLL an alternative?
I'm using 8051's PCA module so I can get x counts per period, but under 48M clock and 100k target my count is 480 but to get to 481 or 479 it needs like 99.8K or 100.2K, and I needed to get a tick every 50Hz not every 200Hz.
My target will be an inductive loop and it will need to detect a motorcycle above it.
UPDATE: Tried to use the frequency without CD4040, my clock can't handle all the stuff I need, 150kHz is only about 6us to do everything I need, so I'm back to CD4040 using div by4. Tried to oversample but did no good, still good at lower frequencies, still awful at higher frequencies. For now I'll try to lower all my frequencies while I can't think a better way to do this.

Comment: There are so many cheap and performant MCUs these days capable of doing that task, but you have to stick with ~40 year old technology?

Comment: @EugeneSh. My MCU is the C8051F382 from SL, it is not that old.

Comment: Is 48MHz an XO?

Comment: 48Mhz is the 8051's internal oscillator not an external crystal.

Comment: Can you make assumptions about the duty cycle of your input signal? (e.g. is it always 50%?)

Comment: For what I saw at the oscilloscope it's 50%, I'm using a transistor so I can square my oscillator's output sine wave.

Comment: Is sampling over multiple periods OK?

Comment: I'm afraid of sampling over multiple periods because 30kHz leads to 33us periods, so I can sample only 3 times before being on my response limit.

Comment: Clk must be <3333 ppm error at all times

Comment: HP made a frequency-time measurement system, that charged up a capacitor proportional to the time residual between the end of the measurement interval (they used a 10MHz clock) and the next zero crossing of the input signal. Thus the high resolution , approx. 100pS, was achieved with a combination of digital and of analog measurement.

Comment: Could you do an F>V conversion and compare the analogue signals for changes and use that to pick the correct prescalar.

Answer (score 1):

You said "I need to measure frequencies between 25kHz and 150kHz", but you didn't say anything about the max rate of frequency change. Assuming the frequency is changing slowly you could get the result "almost" instantly.

Arrange the timers as free-running counter. On each incoming front of measured signal load current value of the free-running counter into memory. Store last, say, 64 values. And at the moment when you need to know the frequency - just subtract some previous N-th value of the free-running counter from the last value. That would be the number of oscillator ticks between the last front and N-th front back in time of measured frequency.

Comment: Using 8051's PCA is the same as a free-running counter. And about the changes, I don't know for sure, for what I read, a motorcycle can alter in like 200Hz to 400Hz so this is why I need a certain precision. I'm changing the code so I can oversample and use the result every 100us to know. I was measuring the period and comparing to a reference, but now I'll only measure each 100us, if it's near to 4800 that will be right, because I'm controlling my max amount of samples so my count for the oscillator without metal near don't go over 4800.

Comment: "Using 8051's PCA is the same as a free-running counter." - No, I meant "using 8051's PCA in the free-running counter setup." That's a bit different to your idea to oversample by using a prescaler to count oscillator ticks between n-th front of measured signal.

Comment: Could you explain/detail further?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you only need 1 pulse to get a frequency. You can increase precision by averaging several pulses of **constant** frequency, but if you input is changing all the time then averaging will **reduce** a precision of instant frequency measurement.

PLL is only good for relatively constant frequencies as well. In a system with fast changing input PLL will only increase latency.

In short - you need to carefully analyze your requirements. If you need "fast and precise" *instantaneous* frequency you can do it by measuring only one period. If you are OK with *average* frequency over some time interval then the desired latency and rate of input changes are the defining factors in choosing sample size. Sample as many times as you can in desired interval and you will be OK. However if input changes too fast then you might have to reduce sampling size to get any meaningful value.

Comment: I do read only one time right now, but the acurracy isn't good. My next test will be reduce the frequency at all, instead of 145k-30k I'll use lower frequency, and use a 4040 as prescaler. But for my calcs I'll need at least 7,8kHz input for the speed response I need.

Comment: Once again - the accuracy is relative for fast changing input. Prescaler does **not** improve accuracy. It pretty much works as hardware averaging. If three consecutive pulses came in and were _precisely_ measured as 30, 50 and 100 kHz, what value do you expect? Average 60 kHz does not correspond to anything physically happening. If you OK with that then oversampling in software simplifies circuit.

Comment: I will try Tony's approach, I'll sample based on my base frequency. I will average 16 values and based on them I'll select how many samples I'll use avg<((100u/48M^-1)/n)+1, so I guarantee that my n samples will always take time in about 100us, this way I wouldn't need any prescaler nor anything just the raw frequency.

Comment: Funny thing is that it is exactly what i suggested ("oversampling in software simplifies circuit"). Maybe it wasn't clearly formulated.

Answer (score 0):

50Hz/150kHz =3333 ppm resolution

You need at least 3333 counts in 100us for 50Hz resolution or a PLL converts from 25KHz to 33.33MHz to 150MHz  or a divide by ratio of 1332 with a slew rate of <10ms.

502MLFT.  :MFG IDT
IC CLK MULTIPLIER PLL 8-SOIC

One could round up to a convenient RPM solution . The use PLL clock to count in 100us and get a minimum of 25k*1332*0.1ms = 3363 counts which meets your resolution and Acquisition time specs.

## Plan B

- measure time interval using 48MHz clock for 10 cycles
- read result,
- invert result
- minimum count of 48M/150k  to get 3200 counts for 10 cycles or more for better resolution

This may be simpler in hardware.

Comment: Forgive me for not understanding you completely, for Plan A - I'll be using 502 so I can input my low frequency and get a few MHz frequency, then my 3333 ppm is solved.  For Plan B, I just cont for 10 periods and then invert my result(NOT my result)?  I can change my hardware but I am just not sure on how to get my precision yet.

Comment: To get 0.1ms intervals and count of >3333 min the multiplier >1332x for plan B , computation time must be short but resolution is adequate using external counters only.

Comment: The plan A is a little complicated to pull off because of the hardware changes, so for fast test I'll use plan B, but couldn't understand the last 2 steps, why invert my results? 48M/150k ten times will be 3200 and inverts to 0xF37F, but I couldn't grasp where to use this inverted result.  About computation time, it isn't a big problem, I'm using assembly so everything goes really fast.

Comment: f=1/count values. * 48MHz /N for N=10 or ?